# How to prompt the 'access web contact' popup window when opening excel file

Tags: excel, popupwindow, web-content, excelquery

I want to prompt the 'access web content' popup window when anyone opens my excel file, so people can use choose their own settings.

At the moment it isn't giving the option to chose your permissions -  I need the prompt to open when the file opens, so the users can choose from 'anonymous', 'windows', 'basic', 'web api' or 'organizational account.

I don't want to have to ask my users to go to the query tool bar, select 'edit', select 'data source settings', select 'edit permissions', select 'edit' under 'credentials in order to open the 'access web contact' popup.

Is there a way I can trigger it to open every time the file is opened?

Comment: I'm looking to force open an excel menu when opening excel. I can see there are ways of forcing custom written messages with VBA, but I'm looking for a way to open one Excel's pre-existing menus when opening file. 

I want to prompt the 'access web content' popup window when anyone opens my excel file, so people can use choose their own settings. 

I have tried to delete the credentials so they're not saved, but it just results in a stack overflow, and doesn't prompt the credentials window.

Answer (score 0):

i just had this problem!

Select Launch Power Query Editor,  then select Data Source Settings, select your data source (mine was already in place), then select Edit Permissions, Edit.

Comment: Hey David, I'm looking for a way to prompt it open when the excel file opens without having to ask them to  Launch Power Query Editor, then select Data Source Settings, select your data source and then edit the permissions. Would you know how to do this?